# How to write to a file in Java of Javafx GUI componets?

Tags: java, xml, javafx, fxml

How can I write a file of GUI components in javafx? For Example:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(userTextField));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I want to write this code into xml or simple text; how?
Please help me.

Comment: 1) open an editor for the desired file type. 2) Create a new file of the desired type 3) Copy & paste 4) Fix syntax (e.g. for xml) 5) save file. (Or was that not the question?)

Answer (score 0):

You mean, how can you write the view class, that specifies all the elements of a stage/window?

In JavaFX you have two different ways of doing it. FXML (which a lot of people seem to prefer - not me though). And the pure code way.

**There's tons of tutorials out there showing you the fxml way and a few (not many - and some bad ones) that show you how to do it in code.**

**Just google "javafx tutorial" or search on youtube, there is tons of stuff that will get you going**

However if you follow my so question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338964/need-review-of-minimal-javafx-example-did-i-understand-those-design-patterns-co

You can see a minimal example of a few design patterns and ideas. Lets see if SO tells us, if I did it correctly ;)

Comment: no there are many ways to write a file java . i want to write  this particular code in a file.

Comment: Do you need help on choosing an editor/ide? It's really hard to figure out what you want to do / what it is that you need help with.

Comment: Maybe your problem is, that you are trying to choose a control as source for your scene, instead of a container?

Comment: I am using intellej . My project is to give user the file of GUI which is automatically created. I want to write GUI components  so the user can re used it again.

Comment: Nope i want save particular components into a file.

Comment: Google: Javafx mvc pattern

Then google: Javafx custom control

Or: Check my example for a minimal code that showcases those things

Comment: My advice would be though: Go do a javafx tutorial - you will learn how to do this stuff

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to create a library that contains a Gui Component for other people to use in their projects. Is that it? If that's correct you can google for "create javafx library".

Comment: I want to create a mockup application in Javafx user select custom controls and can save mockup on runtime. Can is there any solution to save fxml or any file in runtime???

Comment: So you want to program your own scene builder? If so, maybe this is the place to start: https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder

Comment: Or maybe you just wanted to know about filestream?

Comment: yes I also want to know about filestream. How can save GUI components in run time?

Comment: It's working for me. Google "scene builder repository"